# Cauchy criterion uniformly on $S\implies$ sequence converges uniformly on $S$

Tags: uniform-convergence, cauchy-sequences

[image]

Shouldn't the theorem state that the *sequence* of partial sums converges uniformly on $S$?

Comment: Can I ask from what book is this?

Comment: @Masacroso Elementary Analysis: The Theory of Calculus by Kenneth A. Ross

Comment: "the series converges" = "the sequence of partial sums converges". That's the definition of "convergence of a series".

Comment: As Sassatelli said when one is talking of a convergent series then it holds that $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n a_k=c$$ where the LHS is a notation that represent the limit of the RHS.